# Resolving conflicting answers to questions?

Tags: discussion

I was seeking to clarify what the difference between the WGS and the EGM systems was and came across [How are EGM96 and WGS84 related to each other?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24023/how-are-egm96-and-wgs84-related-to-each-other)

The question is about the difference between the EGM96 geoid and the WGS84 ellipsoid.

The comment right below the question states that the accepted answer is correct and that the WGS84 standard includes both the ellipsoid and the geoid, and that the geoid of the WGS84 standard is merely updated to the EGM96 geoid.

The most highly upvoted answer (which is not the accepted answer) states that the accepted answer is wrong and that the WGS84 standard only defines an ellipsoid and the EGM96 standard only defines the geoid.

As a n00b to this field, this gis.stackexchange.com page left me scratching my head. There seems to be no resolution finally as to who's correct.

Comment: The person who writes the question also accepts the most useful answer (to them) regardless of number of votes.

Answer (score 5):

The votes reflects the community's opinion of which answer is better.

The accepted answer is the opinion of the asker as to which answer helped them the most at the time they clicked it.

Unless it is a topic that I know well I trust the votes rather than the acceptance.

Of course both answers may be incorrect.

Comments should only be used to help improve questions and answers, so to me they are the least trustworthy type of post. They are often just quick thoughts and are not subject to the same level of peer review as questions and answers which can be downvoted (not just upvoted).